# How can I pass value from javascript to html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have javascript function that get JSON from another php file but I can't pass value to html file. How can I do it ??

here plese take a look

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON("getquestion.php",function(result)
    {
        document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = result.test_question;   
        testform.textquestion.value = result.test_question;

    });
    </script>
<form name="testform"> 
<div id="question"></div>
<input id="aaa" type="text" name="textquestion"></input>

</body>
```

div:question can show data from result.test_question but input:aaa can't.

Could you please teach me how can I pass value to  or  ? and Can I assign name of function .getJSON and how ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D++pass+value+from+javascript+to+html, 3829 results

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use jQuery properly since you're already using jQuery anyways.

```
$("#question").html(result.test_question);
$('#aaa').val(result.test_question);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
testform.textquestion.value = result.test_question;
```

to

```
document.getElementById('aaa').value = result.test_question;
```

or

```
document.testform.textquestion.value = result.test_question;
```

[Docs for accessing forms using JavaScript here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/forms.html#access)

or as you have linked jQuery .. you could replace

```
document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = result.test_question;   
testform.textquestion.value = result.test_question;
```

with

```
$("#question").html(result.test_question);   
$('#aaa').val(result.test_question);
```

[Docs for `.html()` here](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and [`.val()` here](http://api.jquery.com/val/)