# javascript pass media EventListener to html (html5) media.currentTime

Tags: javascript, html, video, event-listener

*update here is my code edit as you see working) https://codeshare.io/a3ZJ9g

i need to pass on a javascript varible to a html link...

my original question was here [HTML5 video get currentTime not working with media events javscript addEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49353272/html5-video-get-currenttime-not-working-with-media-events-javscript-addeventlist)

working code:

```
  <script>
  var media = document.getElementById('myVideo');

  // durationchange
  var isdurationchange = function(e) {
    $("#output").html(media.currentTime);
 var x = document.createElement("a");

  };


 media.addEventListener("timeupdate", isdurationchange, true)
 </script>
```

that code works
but i need it to echo the currentTime value to the html page such as

```
document.write("<a href=/time.htm?currentTime='.media.addEventListener("timeupdate", isdurationchange, true).'>link</a>;);
```

so it would print out

```
 <a href=time.htm?currentTime=currenttimefromjavascript>link</a>
```

thank you

i did read:
[how to pass javascript variable to html tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48941087/how-to-pass-javascript-variable-to-html-tag)

[How can I pass value from javascript to html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685060/how-can-i-pass-value-from-javascript-to-html)

someone suggested:

```
 // insert the `a` somewhere appropriate so it can be clicked on:
 const a = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
 a.textContent = 'Link to current time';
 const isdurationchange = function(e) {
 a.href = `\\time.htm?currentTime=${media.currentTime}`;
};
```

but where does that go?

Comment: I don't think that a constantly changing href=url will affect another page  unless it gets clicked. Wouldn't it make more sense to just get currentTime when the link is actually clicked?

Comment: whatever would make sense,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.write` tries to write to the current document. If the document has already been processed, the document will be replaced with a blank one with your argument. You don't want that; use the proper DOM methods instead.

If, for an element you create dynamically, you want to change its `href` on every `timeupdate`, you would do:

```
// insert the `a` somewhere appropriate so it can be clicked on:
const a = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
a.textContent = 'Link to current time';
const isdurationchange = function(e) {
  a.href = `\\time.htm?currentTime=${media.currentTime}`;
};
```

Comment: thanks but iam still confused on where that would go..................  i tried a few places

Comment: Where what would go? If you're asking about the `a`, it's up to you, insert it wherever you think would look nicest so that users can click on it.

Comment: well i put in the script tag and i see nothing

Comment: If you want people to see a dynamically created element, you should put it in the body somewhere, as a child of a proper element, not as a child of a `script` tag

Comment: i put 
<script>
const a = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
a.textContent = 'Link to current time';
const isdurationchange = function(e) {
  a.href = `\\time.htm?currentTime=${media.currentTime}`;
};

</script>  in the body nothing shows up

Comment: I was showing you how to define the `a` and the `isdurationchange` function - you should put it in the context of your full script, of course, with `var media = document.getElementById('myVideo');` and `media.addEventListener("timeupdate", isdurationchange, true)`

Comment: here is the code  you can edit with codeshare thank you

Comment: Don't re-declare `a` and `isdurationchange`, that won't work, you have to replace the parts of the old code with the new... https://jsfiddle.net/c3pgxa8k/

Comment: thanks , although i got ti working thanks you  , i will never figure out hwo it works. i get php, timer function in visual basic ..  your code puts the link at the very bottom of the page............. even if its within a div

Comment: That's why I said "insert the `a` somewhere appropriate so it can be clicked on", it's your HTML, you can figure out where to put it

Comment: where ever i add the script you provided the "link to time" displays at teh very last line.

Comment: That's why I said you should insert the `a` wherever you want, don't just copy my code character-for-character - you have to decide where to put the `a` that gets inserted, it's your site.

Comment: CertainPerformance - im not trying to go line by line copy, i am trying to figure it out from scratch........

Comment: i put a.textContent = 'Link to current time'; in script tags but it did not print anything